# Deploying on remote server using cloudify

Tags: cloudify

I am new to cloudify. Can someone please help me in the following?

1. Deploying a sample application on remote server. Right now I am running the command:

   ```
   cfy local init --blueprint-path blueprint.yaml --inputs '{"webserver_port": "8080", "host_ip":"ec2-hostname"}'
   ```

but it will launch the application on local Cloudify server. Even `ec2-hostname` is the remote server. But still it is deploying on local server.

Can someone please share the steps required to deploy the application on remote server using Cloudify?

I will highly appreciate it.

Thanks,
Sanjiv

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the example described here: http://docs.getcloudify.org/3.3.0/intro/getting-started/ then this is an example to be used in local mode only.

For a more advanced example which can be installed on a remote server, look here: https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-hello-world-example

Comment: I am using latest 3.3 cloudify version and using the default blueprint.yaml file coming with cloudify sample application. I am not quite sure where and what we need to change in blueprint.yaml to deploy it on remote server.